# language french grammar in grammar

Tags: packages, grammar

I use latex online with the overleaf website and I have a problem with the implementation of French language I used its packaging and nothing changes from English to French
and here are the packaging used

```
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

and here are the errors even if I put the packages

[image]

Comment: `Introdcution` is indeed a typo…

Comment: ah yes now that i have seen and for "problématique" ?

Comment: It's fine. Maybe their software expects a grave accent as in ‘problème’? In which case it's their software which would be problematic…

Comment: thank you ,is that there is another site online that does not stutter like this one and that accepts French dictionary ?

Comment: I don't know – personally, I work  with the system installed on my computer.

Comment: OK thank you very much

Comment: is that there is powerful and simple software for their installations which avoids as it is bug ?

Comment: @mamymamy  if you haven't selected French it's user error not a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spell checking in the editor is completely separate from the tex typesetting and needs to be specified in the overleaf menu not in the latex code.

the main menu on the left has a spell check language option under settings

[image]

Comment: thank you very much it works